# Andriod EditText lose focus after clicking on Expandable list view parent items

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have expandable list view each view has multiple text views. For keep tracking of edit text focus and its data I am calling **setOnFocus** listener. But it is working only when I change my textview focus. When I select or click New Parent item I am losing its focus.

**Code Sample**

```
final ViewHolder holder;

@Override
public View getChildView(final int parent, final child, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

 holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        if (view == null) {
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.editText = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecordComment);
        } else {
           holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        holder.editText.setText(map.get("ed_" + parent + "" + child));

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
              map.put("ed_" + parent + "" + child, holder.editText.getText().toString());
        }

    });
}
```

Code working fine if I change focus of editText but it fails to store if I click on next parent item

Is their any way that I can use Key Up function??

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `TextWatcher` class if you would like use onKeyUp function.

```
EditText tv_filter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filter);

TextWatcher fieldValidatorTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (filterLongEnough()) {
            populateList();
        }
    }

    private boolean filterLongEnough() {
        return tv_filter.getText().toString().trim().length() > 2;
    }
};
tv_filter.addTextChangedListener(fieldValidatorTextWatcher);
```